# Lifting inside continuations

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I have a continuation with type `(a -> b) -> b`. I also have a function that is "almost" a suitable context, with type `Monad m => a -> m b`. Is there a way to upgrade the continuation from `(a -> b) -> b` to `(a -> m b) -> m b`? My instinct is no, but I'd like to be wrong about this.

Comment: I assume the function actually has that type for some specific monad? Because if it's polymorphic over monads, you can use it at type `a -> Identity b` and recover a function of type `a -> b`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is indeed impossible, at least in the general case where `m` can be an arbitrary monad.

Assume the monad `m` is the continuation monad `(- -> r) -> r`. (I omit the `newtype` wrapper for clarity).

Then, what you want is a way to convert `(a -> b) -> b` into `(a -> (b -> r) -> r) -> (b -> r) -> r`. In other words, you want a polymorphic term of type

```
t :: ((a -> b) -> b) -> (a -> (b -> r) -> r) -> (b -> r) -> r
```

We prove that `t` can not exist by contradiction. Let us assume such a `t` exists. We can specialize it by choosing `r~a` and `b~Void` (the empty type).

```
t :: ((a -> Void) -> Void) -> (a -> (Void -> a) -> a) -> (Void -> a) -> a
```

Now, recall we have a (total!) function `absurd :: Void -> a` (essentially, `absurd x = case x of {}`). We then get

```
\ x -> t x (\y _ -> y) absurd
:: ((a -> Void) -> Void) -> a
```

By the [Curry-Howard isomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curry%E2%80%93Howard_correspondence) the following would be a logical tautology in intuitionistic logic:

```
((A -> False) -> False) -> A
```

But the formula above is `Not (Not A) -> A`, i.e., double negation elimination, which is known to be impossible to prove in intuitionistic logic. Hence, we get a contradiction, and we have to conclude that there is no term `t` of that type.

Note that `t` could exist for other monads `m`.